# add onClick listener on Android ListView With SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I didn't found the solution with the search :(

I'm programming an application for reading RSS feeds.
I'm using a listview for putting a screen title and description of every feed into 2 textview. I realized that with a SimpleAdapter.

In my project I have 2 classes: MainActivity and AsynkTask.
In mainActivity I execute the asyncTask that reads RSS and puts them into the adapter and the listview

Now, how can I add a click listener on the listview for opening every feed into the browser?

I hope that I've explained correctly the problem and I'm sorry for my very bad english!
Thanks to all.

PS: if you need some of my code i will post it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112758/how-to-get-onitemclicklistener-for-simpleadapter-working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the onCreate method of your MainActivity, if it's a ListActivity, you need to get a reference to your list view like so:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
```

Then add a click listener to it like so:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) { 
  //Open the browser here
}
```

Comment: on the first line, Eclipse send me this error: "   The method getListView() is undefined for the type MainActivity "

Comment: Are you adding a list view to your layout and using a plain Activity or are you using a ListActivity?  The ListActivity is designed for activities that only have a list view as an element.  If you're using an Activity and have a ListView on your layout, you'd need to get access to it like this:
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.idOfListViewOnLayout);

Comment: ok, done.. but when i call setonitemclicklistener eclise send me this error: Multiple markers at this line
 - OnItemClickListener cannot be resolved to a type
 - The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the 
  arguments (new OnItemClickListener(){})

Comment: Are you importing OnItemClickListener in your class:

import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

Comment: yes sorry i've solved in this way.. sorry for my mistake ... just an  explanation.. to take the position of the element i've clicked how can i do? i've tried with lv.getSelectedItemPosition() but eclipse tell me that lv have to be a final variable but declaring lv as final the app crash when i click :S

Comment: The position that is passed in to the onClickListener will be the position in your listview that is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

On your list view, you need to use setOnItemClickListener

Comment: I have to set this property into the AsynkTask class or mainActivity class?