# ListView onItemClickListener doesnt do anything

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-listfragment

I have a ListFragment with used as a tab. I am trying to use OnItemSelectedListener on my ListView which has to start another activity and put specific extra in the intend based on the selected item. I am using the following code:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_priority_tab, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    List<String> printedList = calculateProportions();
    ArrayAdapter<String> expensesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(mContext,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, printedList);
    listView.setAdapter(expensesAdapter);
    listView.setClickable(true);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ListPriority.class);
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    intent.putExtra("priority", "low");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    intent.putExtra("priority", "med");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    intent.putExtra("priority", "high");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    intent.putExtra("priority", "obsolete");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

I dont have any error or warning but my activity doesnt start.When i debug the app and i click on any of the items i dont even reach my breakpoint.

my ListView in XML:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

my java code is in onCreateView in the ListFragment

Comment: is your breakpoint at the new Intent line and it isnt called?

Comment: yes it is! I cant reach anything in my OnClickListener.

Comment: Since you're using a simple adapter check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418255/add-onclick-listener-on-android-listview-with-simpleadapter

Comment: I tried using getListView() but it gives me an error

Comment: this is the whole method. I only skip 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     and
       return rootView;

Comment: i dont have super.onCreateView() and i dont use getView() anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ListFragment` handles its own `OnItemClickListener`. Instead of setting a listener, override [`onListItemClick()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29)

Comment: ... which is setted in `onViewCreated` ... and it removes previous ListView `OnItemClickListener` ... nice finding :)

Comment: You are right buddy! That solved my issue. I never ever heard of that! Thank you ,I learned something new!

Comment: Similarly, you can use `ListFragment.setListAdapter()` instead of calling `setAdapter()` directly on your list. `ListFragment` is designed so that you usually don't need to touch the list directly.

Answer (score 0):

**In your java class, your id declaration is wrong:**

Change from,

```
ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

To

```
ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
```

**And your xml id declaration is wrong:**

Change from,

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

To

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: just try it ... obviously such modification will throw `Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`

Comment: the method and funda said by me is also right way to do this.

Comment: For `ListFragment` it is not right method! - the only case when you can have your own id for main `ListView` in `ListFragment` is when main view is a `ListView` (`getView()` (which implicates that also `onCreateView` ) returns `ListView` - which also implicates that there is no need for own id) please analyze the ListFragment!